# Determine if the autonomous system is Hamiltonian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the autonomous system $\dot{x}=-y-\alpha ^2xy^2$ and $\dot{y}=x^3$, where $\alpha$ is a real parameter.

- (a) For which values of $\alpha$ is this system Hamiltonian? For each case, find the Hamiltonian.
- (b) For each value of $\alpha$, find all equilibrium solutions of the above system. Can the principle of linearized stability be used to determine their stability?
- (c) Show that for all $\alpha \in R$ the origin is a stable equilibrium. (Hint: Can you use Hamiltonian functions from (a)?).

So the way to solve this is to use the fact that $\dot{x}=\partial H/\partial y$ and $\dot{y}=-\partial H/\partial x$, where $H(x,y)$ is the Hamiltonian for this system. But then $H(x,y)=-\frac{x^4}{4}+V(y)$ and $H(x,y)=-\frac{y^2}{2}+V(x)$ but I don't know how to solve this further.  The only way to have Hamiltonian is if $\alpha =0$, ie. $H(x,y)=-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{y^2}{2}$. Then we will have system $\dot{x}=-y$ and $\dot{y}=x^3$. Is this right?

So only $\alpha$ that would work is if $\alpha =0$ and then only equilibrium will be the origin $(0,0)$. Then the Jacobian would be $Df=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 3x^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$. So then what is equilibrium solution of this system and can principle of linearized stability be used to determine its stability?

How do we show for $\alpha \in R$, the origin is a stable equilibrium?

I am not sure if I got the Hamiltonian correct, since I am assuming only $\alpha =0$ will give a Hamiltonian. But the questions assume there are other $\alpha$ values that will work just as well.
Please help.

Comment: The linearization theorem is not applicable if there are eigenvalues with zero real parts. However, consider what you obtain if you take your $-H$ as a Lyapunov function candidate for the $\alpha \neq 0$ case.

Comment: But what about the Hamiltonian function for this system? It seems that if alpha is 0, then only Hamiltonian can be formed. Can non-zero alpha give a Hamiltonian? If so, then what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general Hamiltonion system in the two configuration variables $x$ and $y$ takes the form

$\dot x = \dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial y}, \tag 1$

$\dot y = -\dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial x}, \tag 2$

where $H(x, y)$ is a scalar function of $x$ and $y$.  If we assume $H(x, y)$ is of class $C^2$, then we may form the divergence of the vector field

$(\dot x, \dot y) = \left (\dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial y}, -\dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial x} \right ) \tag 3$

and find

$\nabla \cdot (\dot x, \dot y) = \nabla \cdot \left (\dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial y}, -\dfrac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial x} \right )$
$= \dfrac{\partial^2 H(x, y)}{\partial x \partial y} - \dfrac{\partial^2 H(x, y)}{\partial y \partial x} = 0; \tag 4$

this is a *necessary condition* for $(\dot x, \dot y)$ to be Hamiltonion; applying this criterion to the vector field given by

$\dot x = -y - \alpha^2 xy^2, \tag 5$

$\dot y = x^3 \tag 6$

$\nabla \cdot (\dot x, \dot y)  = \dfrac{\partial (-y - \alpha^2xy^2)}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial x^3}{\partial y} = -\alpha^2 y^2 = 0 \tag 7$

if and only if

$\alpha = 0, \tag 8$

in which case the system becomes

$\dot x = -y, \tag 9$

$\dot y = x^3, \tag{10}$

and it is easy to see that taking

$H(x, y) = -\dfrac{y^2}{2} - \dfrac{x^4}{4} \tag{10.5}$

yields the equations (9)-(10).  Thus is part (a) resolved.

As for part (b), for any $\alpha$ the equilibrium points satisfy

$0 = \dot x = -y - \alpha^2 xy^2 \tag{11}$

and

$0 = \dot y = x^3; \tag{12}$

now (12) forces

$x = 0, \tag{13}$

and substituting this into (11) in turn forces

$y = 0 \tag{14}$

as well.  Thus the only critical point occurs at

$(x, y) = (0, 0) \tag{15}$

no matter what value

$\alpha \in \Bbb R \tag{16}$

may take.  We may attempt to investigate its stability by forming the Jacobian matrix

$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial{\dot x}}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial{\dot x}}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial{\dot y}}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial{\dot y}}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}; \tag{17}$

using (5)-(6) and (15) we find

$J(0, 0) =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0  & 0 \end{bmatrix},\tag{18}$

the characteristic polynomial of which is

$\det(J(0, 0) - \lambda I) = \det \left ( \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & -1 \\ 0  & -\lambda \end{bmatrix} \right ) = \lambda^2, \tag{19}$

the (repeated) root of which is

$\lambda = 0; \tag{20}$

$\lambda$ is of course the eigenvalue of $J(0, 0)$, and since it has $0$ real part, linearization cannot be used to determine the stability of $(0, 0)$.

We turn to part (c).  We consider the function $H(x, y)$ as in (10.5); we observe that this function takes its maximum value $0$ uniquely at $(0, 0)$, and that the other level sets of $H(x, y)$ are of the form

$-\dfrac{y^2}{2} - \dfrac{x^4}{4} = \text{constant} < 0, \tag{21}$

that is, they are closed "ellipsoidal" curves symmetrically surrounding the origin.  We compute $\dot H(x, y)$ along the trajectories of (5)-(6):

$\dot H(x, y) = -y\dot y - x^3 \dot x; \tag{22}$

in light of (5), (6) this becomes

$\dot H(x, y) = -yx^3 - x^3 (-y - \alpha^2 xy^2)$
$= -yx^3 + x^3y + \alpha^2 x^4y^2 = \alpha^2x^4y^2 \ge 0; \tag{23}$

in accord with (23), we see that $H(x, y)$ is nondecreasing along the trajectories of (5)-(6); thus any orbit of (5)-(6) which passes through a point interior to an "ellipsoidal" level set of $H(x, y)$ forever remains in this interior region of the plane.  Since such regions may be taken arbitrarily
small by choosing $H(x, y)$ sufficiently close to yet less than $0$, $(0, 0)$ is a stable point of the system (5)-(6).

Comment: So my hunch was right. You verified the Hamiltonian and validated that only $\alpha =0$. My confusion was that the question that I got this from stated "For which values of $\alpha$" in parts a) and b) implying there could be more than one value of $\alpha$. So I thought $\alpha =0$ may not be the only solution. But your solution verified that $\alpha =0$ is the only value that will give a Hamiltonian. Thanks for your help! It is very well written.

Comment: @John:  Thanks for the kind words.  If you find my answer helpful, you might consider "accepting" it.  ***Cheers!***

Comment: @John:  Oh, I see you already did.  ***Thanks!***

Comment: Just one  question - for equation (7) you concluded $-\alpha ^2y^2=0$ if and only if $\alpha =0$. What if $y=0$, then can't $\alpha$ be nonzero?

Comment: @John:  for the vector field to be Hamiltonian, we must have $\nabla \cdot (\dot x, \dot y) = 0$ *identically*, not just when $y = 0$; so $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Robert.